# Including screenshot of iPad/iPhone in my App

Tags: iphone, submission

I've been reading through Apples submission guidelines and was wondering if anyone has had experience including screenshots inside their app.

I want to include some screenshots of the Home Screen and maybe some other parts of iOS in my app.

Is this going to lead to instant rejection?

Comment: What would be the purpose of this? Could you detail a little more how this screenshots would be? What would it display?

Answer (score 1):

Why should you include parts of iOS in your App screenshots? I'm not thinking of anything (except notifications or showing App workflow) that could be included. I think that if you have a great reason for including those screenshots (like describing the workflow of your App), you have a chance to be accepted.

A common sense is to look screenshots of other apps - if they have it, you *could* too.

Answer (score 0):

No as of now there is no rejection if you use images from your app into your application.There is no reason in rejecting that.Hope this helps You can go throuch this guidelines on   http://developer.apple.com/appstore/guidelines.html , http://mobileorchard.com/avoiding-iphone-app-rejection-from-apple and  http://iphoneincubator.com/blog/app-store/rejections  .Hope this helps.